# what does “steering meeting” means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I saw my international manager to be in status steering meeting. what does this mean.I checked and seems to me like an advisory meeting perhaps. Could you advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the following connotation of ***[steering](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/steering):***

> A ***steering committee or a steering group*** is a group of people that organizes the early stages of a project, and makes sure it progresses in a satisfactory way.

(Collins Dictionary)